# Json to csv in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I know this question has been answered... using below

```
print("name,id,email");
db.User.find().forEach(function(user){
  print(user.name+","+user._id.valueOf()+","+user.email);
});
```

But I am facing issue while reading the records whose fields start with number.

Below is the O/P

```
db.Detail.find({"Comment": /ABCD/,"CreateDt": { "$gte" : ISODate("2015-12-03") }},{'Data.01-WaitQueue.EndTime':1}).limit().pretty()
{
    "Data" : {
            "01-WaitQueue" : {
                    "EndTime" : ISODate("2015-12-03T02:39:11Z")
            }
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("565fab4ea5c75a3c4f000000")
}
```

When I am using forEach to convert into CSV

```
db.Detail.find({"Comment": /ABCD/,"CreateDt": { "$gte" : ISODate("2015-12-03") }},{'Data.01-WaitQueue.EndTime':1}).limit().forEach(function(PD) {
      print(PD.Data.01-WaitQueue.EndTime +":"+ PD._id);
});
```

I am getting below error

```
Fri Dec  4 07:11:38 SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (shell):1
```

Can someone please help me in rectifying it?

Comment: What is the name of the field? `01`? Or `01-WaitQueue`? That's the same ambiguity Mongo is fighting with here. Use `Data['01-WaitQueue']` syntax for properties with invalid names.

Comment: field name is 01-WaitQueue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown because of the `print` line has syntax error.
Instead of

```
print(PD.Data.01-WaitQueue.EndTime +":"+ PD._id);
```

Try this instead:

```
print(PD.Data['01-WaitQueue'].EndTime +":"+ PD._id);
```